# Change revert branch naming used by Github web

Tags: github

I was wondering if it's possible to change the way Github names its revert branches whenever you click "Revert merge" in the web interface of a merged PR. Specifically, I want to add a prefix which tells CI to create a job on a different node (somewhat convoluted setup). Is there some setting in Github or some kind of config file?